# How to check if label in VB.net (VS2008) has multiple lines?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a method that saves form controls data to a text file, including its text. IF a label has multiple lines, this breaks the text file writing multiple lines to it.

I was instructed to simply ignore multiple-line labels and don't include it in the file, but I don't know how to check whether or not a label has can multiple lines or not so I can throw in an 'if' statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a Label where the user has added a Hard Return, causing multiple lines, or a Label that wraps? Or Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for new lines in the label like this:

```
If Not lblText.Text.Contains(Environment.NewLine) Then
```

So if the label has a newline, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Test for something like this

```
Label1.Text.Contains(Environment.NewLine)
```

[Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
myLabel.Text.Contains(vbCrlf)
```

Sorry, VB.net isn't my first language.